# boot ubuntu 12.04 LTS from flashdrive

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, usb

I recently downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a flashdrive to try Linux out and installed the file and used the universal USB installer to install that file onto my flashdrive. After changing the boot sequence on my laptop, I got a screen asking me for what language I wanted so I clicked English, but after that it just gave be a black screen and I can type stuff on it. I rebooted my laptop and I got the black screen again, not the Ubuntu interface.

Am I doing anything wrong here while trying to boot up from my flashdrive, because I really want to give Linux a try!

Any help would be appreciated on this!

Edit: The question that my question appears to be similar to asks for where to get the ISO file, not why I'm getting a black screen every time I boot up from my pendrive. I have the iso downloaded from unetbootin on my flashdrive and my boot sequence changed in my bios settings, but every time I boot up ubuntu, I get a purple screen and then I get a black screen and I can type words, numbers, etc on it.

Comment: P.S. I'm completely new to this, so there might be something stupid that I forgot to do.

Comment: yes,try unetbootin.

Comment: well apparently after deleting a folder from my flashdrive, I was able to get the Ubuntu Logo after clicking enter on "Try Ubuntu Before installing," and while it was loading, it turned up an error that said: 
"Unable to find a file containing a live file system"

Comment: plz format the flashdrive to fat32 filesystem and recreate bootable usb via unetbootin.

Comment: the flashdrive is fat32 format, but I'll try using unetbootin this time.

Comment: so after formating flashdrive again and using unetbootin to create a bootable usb, I rebooted my laptop and got a screen with options, (default, help, try ubuntu without installing it, etc), but when I hit enter on any of the options, the screen minimizes in the top left corner and I get a black screen where I can type anything I want. Still don't know what I'm doing wrong.
And TomKat, don't know who that is but thats not me.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself. AND "a duplicate" doesn't say you posted it twice but that your question is probably the same (with the same answers).

Comment: Possible duplicate: ["My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people report problems when trying to use Universal.
Try UNetbootin or Startup Disk Creator, (from the Live DVD).